# Strange behaviour (for me) with ifPresentOrElse of an Optional in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following code:

```
Optional<Person> oldestPerson = personenListe.stream().collect(Collectors.reducing(maxAge));
Consumer<Person> personPrinter = p -> System.out.println("The oldest is : " + p.getName());
Runnable noPersonMessagePrinter = () -> System.out.println("There is no person");
oldestPerson.ifPresentOrElse(personPrinter,noPersonMessagePrinter );
```

My IDE underlines ifPresentOrElse as red, because it doesn't find the signiture, but from my view it should be correct.

Any guess?

Comment: BTW `ifPresentOrElse` java 9

Comment: @manfromnowhere That seems to be the exact problem here if the OP is using Java 8...

Comment: +1 for the exemplary precise question title (in addition you’ve got short, verifiable example and precise description of error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `ifPresentOrElse` was added in Java 9, so it is not available in Java 8. That is why your IDE marks it as invalid: that method does not exist in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

`ifPresentOrElse()` only valid in Java 9, but if you're using Spring Boot, use can find `ifPresentOrElse()` method in `Optionals` class. It does the same function for you.